# Recommended English-Esperanto dictionaries?

Tags: books

There are a number of dictionaries on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/157-0310109-5280819?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Esperanto%20and%20English%20Dictionary), but I'm not sure which ones are relevant and of high quality. I've seen Wells used as a source for a number of answers here on Stack Exchange. We have had a number of questions about electronic dictionaries, but none (or few?) about actual dead-tree versions.

Which paper dictionaries are recommended?

Comment: Americans would be advised to check the Retbutiko of Esperanto-USA rather than Amazon. CEED is $27 from EUSA and about $80 from Amazon.

Answer (score 4):

Wells is a good choice and is probably the best two-way English-Esperanto dictionary I've held in my hands. The English in this book is more British than American.

Benson's Complete Esperanto-English dictionary has more detail in it, but it's only one-way, so you'll want either a two-way dictionary or an Esperanto-Esperanto dictionary to go with it.

I also have Krause's Großes Wörterbuch Esperanto-Deutsch which is also one-way, but it goes in the other direction.

I think you'd be happy with any of these (well, assuming you speak British, American, and German) but I've been told that Amazon tends to be kind of expensive for these kinds of things. You might want to look into various Esperanto book services.

Comment: I got a copy of Wells on eBay for not much money. For all but the most recent additions it seems to provide very good coverage.

Answer (score 1):

I have McLinen's *Pocket Esperanto Dictionary*.  It has a very convenient size, but unfortunately I found a couple of flaws.  Mostly I wanted it for reading Esperanto books, but the majority of the dictionary is English to Esperanto, while the Esperanto to English part is a little scant.  It also has errors, frequent enough to notice I think.  I do use it if "reading offline", so it is not bad, though I wish it were higher quality, and a bit more thorough in the Esperanto to English coverage.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the credentials of John Wells and also the reputation of Mondial publishing, I would recommend English-Esperanto-English Dictionary (2010 Edition)
https://www.amazon.co.uk/English-Esperanto-English-Dictionary-2010-Christopher-Wells/dp/1595691499

> Wells was the president of the World Esperanto Association (UEA) from
>   1989 to 1995. He has previously been the president of the Esperanto
>   Association of Britain and of the Esperanto Academy.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_C._Wells#Esperanto

Esperanto USA recommends this one on their website:
COMPREHENSIVE ENGLISH-ESPERANTO DICTIONARY
http://esperanto-usa.org/retbutiko/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=140&products_id=3110